# xamarin forms picker binding selected value to NgModel like angular

Tags: forms, xamarin, ionic-framework, ngmodel

I have a dynamic model of the user entity with JSON type. I need to show a form to select the value foreach property with dropdownlist then insert to the db. Like a entity of user has property sex and age(property can be edit by endpage by customer) . 
the example result like below:

```
[
      {
        "bindValue": null,
        "title": "sex",
        "code":"sex",
        "property": {
          "option": [
            "male",
            "female"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bindValue": null,
        "code":"grade",
        "property": {
          "option": [
            "2",
            "3"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

with angular ionic project i can code with this:

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let x of dynamicdroplist">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label fixed>{{x.title}}</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="x.bindValue">
          <ion-select-option *ngFor="let y of x.property.option" value="{{y}}">{{y}}</ion-select-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
```

when user change the select value, it'll bind "ngModel" to x.bindvalue, i can filter the code and the binvalue data to send to api.

But with xamarin forms i don't know how to bind select value to bindvalue

```
foreach(var item in field){
     StackLayout layout = new StackLayout().LoadFromXaml("<StackLayout></StackLayout>");
     layout.Children.Add(new Label().LoadFromXaml("<Label Text=\"" + item.Title + "\"></Label>"));
     var picker = new Picker { Title = item.Title };
     foreach (var e in item.Property.option)
     {
          picker.Items.Add(e);
     }          
     layout.Children.Add(picker);
      _stackLayout.Children.Add(layout);
}
```

I want to know how can i code this with xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the `Picker.SelectedItem` to `bindValue` in `TwoWay`, then if user change the select value, the `bindValue` in the model will update:

```
 picker.BindingContext = item;
 picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "bindValue",mode:BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

Here is the a sample code you can refer:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    StackLayout _stackLayout;

    List<RootObject> field = new List<RootObject>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _stackLayout = new StackLayout();


        field.Add(new RootObject() { bindValue = "", title = "sex", code ="sex", property = new Property() { option = new List<string>() { "male","female"} } });
        field.Add(new RootObject() { bindValue = "", title = "grade", code = "grade", property = new Property() { option = new List<string>() { "2", "3" } } });

        foreach (RootObject item in field)
        {
            StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
            layout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = item.title });
            var picker = new Picker { Title = item.title };

            //set the BindingContext here
            picker.BindingContext = item;

            foreach (string e in item.property.option)
            {
                picker.Items.Add(e);

                //bind the value here
                picker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedItemProperty, "bindValue",mode:BindingMode.TwoWay);
            }
            layout.Children.Add(picker);

            picker.SelectedIndexChanged += Picker_SelectedIndexChanged;

            _stackLayout.Children.Add(layout);
        }

        Content = _stackLayout;
    }

    private void Picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check the value change in field
        RootObject r1 = field[0];
        Console.WriteLine(r1.bindValue);

        RootObject r2 = field[1];
        Console.WriteLine(r2.bindValue);
    }
}


public class Property
{
    public List<string> option { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string bindValue { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public Property property { get; set; }
}
```

Refer: [data-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value programatically, just access it using the picker variable you declared;

```
picker.SelectedItem
```

Otherwise if you want to bind it to the UI, you can;

```
myLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("SelectedItem", source: picker));
```